# Выбор надежной формы

Tags: склонение

Подскажите, пожалуйста, как правильно писать: "Материалы по анализу..." или "Материалы анализа..."?

Comment: Не хватает контекста.

Answer (score 1):

И то и другое корректно использовать.

Вот, например, документ Госплана: "О Методических материалах по планированию, учету и калькулированию себестоимости продукции на предприятиях машиностроения и металлообработки":

> **Нормативно-правовые акты по планированию, учету и анализу деятельности
>   предприятия.** Порядок разработки перспективных и годовых планов
>   хозяйственно-финансовой и производственной деятельности предприятия.

Должностная инструкция экономиста по планированию:

> Экономист по планированию должен знать:
>   1.    4.1. Законодательные акты, постановления, распоряжения, приказы, другие руководящие, методические и нормативные **материалы по
>   планированию, учету и анализу деятельности предприятия**.

https://www.rabotka.ru/job_description/382.php

А вот название научной работы:

> ОБРАЗ ИСТОРИЧЕСКОЙ НАУКИ (**НА МАТЕРИАЛАХ АНАЛИЗА ГАЗЕТЫ** «КУЛЬТУРА И
>   ЖИЗНЬ»)

Возможно сказать и так: "Материалы анализа урока".